# Horizontal scroll bar at a fixed width

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

Please help, I have spent almost two days but not able to determine what is causing horizontal scroll bar on the site at width 1135px. The main wrapper has a width of 1135px which is the max width of the site. so at the viewport size 1135px there should be no horizontal scroll but something is causing the site to horizontally scroll at that width. I have checked all the paddings and widths of all the element and have also tried deleting the nodes one by one to isolate the issue but no luck. Seeking help from someone more experienced and has dealt with such issues. 
[[Link to the site]](http://dev.calyxagency.com/horizoncapital/site-new/)

Comment: i couldnt replicate the issue i  trieed in chrome,firefox and ie all latest version no horizontal bar is coming

Comment: tested in both firefox and chrome. Have also tested using online tool at 1135px viewport size.

Comment: @user2563864 I don't see any horizontal scrollbar!

Comment: can u mention the online tool u tested?

Comment: https://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: by default  for me 1024*600 comes i need to change to 1135*600 and check rt?

Comment: yes there is an option to set the custom size, which is an angle like icon at the top next to televison icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide horizontal  scrollers with this css

```
html {
      overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

if you want to bring it back on any pages add

```
<style type='text/css'>

.element { 
     overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

</style>
```

Use this jquery

```
if($(window).outerWidth() < '1135px'){
     $('html').css({overflow: scroll});
} else {
     $('html').css({overflow: hidden});
}
```

Make sure you have an ajax file

Comment: this is not  a good solution..it will hide all the horizontal scrollers in the page..he might need the horizontal scroll for some functionality in the application.

Comment: @ABertil what about `overflow: auto;` ?

Comment: If he ever need the scrollers on the page he can make a style tag and in it do `html {overflow-x: scroll !important;}`

Comment: @OllieCole serious? it will then definetly hide them all!

Comment: @OllieCole `!important` destroys he whole cascade! see this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: @Ollie Colie that too wont work then for that div scroll will be always der...:)

Comment: Thanks. I know about overflow:hidden property but that is not the solution for me.

Comment: The site must scroll horizontally if the viewport width is any less than 1135px. And should be the default behaviour without any media queries

Comment: @Ollie Colie. thanks for your input. But we are still manipulating the DOM here without actually fixing the problem. If I set overflow:hidden at 1135px width with media query or jquery, I m losing the text which is at the corner of the window as it gets hidden. You wont see it on the home page but any other page you can see it on the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Found
The issue is with this tag

```
media="all"
#viewport 
{
padding: 30px;
}
```

Remove padding and see the horizontal bar goes off..If u need padding try another alternative not in viewport..

Let me have a look hope i can help you..:)..

check the attached images and what i have done

before   image

[image]

after image

[image]

Thanks
AB

Comment: m sorry I don't see that style anywhere

Comment: Yes I see it but that element and style is not the part of the css of the actual site. You can only see this property while testing it with this tool. so removing it here will not change anything on the site.

Comment: yeah dat padding is realted to screenfly...so that doesnt give the exact look..you can remove it in developer tools and you will get the exact way the site looks in various resolutions..dats why in my rowser der was no issue viewing your sites..issue comes only in screenfly because of its padding

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But I find it weird that you don't see the scroll bar if you view the site in your browser at 1135px width. Coz if I resize my browser window to exact 1135px then the scrollbar appears. So at my end it is not just in screenfly but also in the browser. Infact I am getting it upto 1149px browser width

Comment: Then it might be resolution issue...I guess..try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Finally I figured it out, it was a row class used by the theme which had a width set on it and it was used in both body content and the footer hence deleting one any one node didn't fix it. But thanks for all your help, appreciate it.